# Is it true that $E[X|X^2] = X$?

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be an integrable random variable. I want to know if it is true that $E[X|X^2] = X$.

At first I thought it is true because $X$ is measurable with respect of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X^2$, because $f(x) = x^2$ is a Borel measurable function. But after a while I noticed that:
$$\sigma(f(X))\subset \sigma(X)$$
The proof is in [this pdf document](http://sas.uwaterloo.ca/~dlmcleis/s901/chapt3.pdf), Theorem 52.

As a consecuence, $X$ is not necesarily measurable with respect of $\sigma(f(X))$, so $E[X|X^2] = X$ is false.

I want to know if I'm wrong, or if there's is a better way to check if $E[X|X^2] = X$ is true or not.

Comment: You explain neatly why $E(X\mid X^2)=X$ cannot hold in general. There is no general formula for $E(X\mid X^2)$ but, when $X$ has a PDF $f$, one finds that $E(X\mid X^2)=u(X^2)$ where, for every nonnegative $z$, $$u(z)=\sqrt{z}\frac{f(\sqrt{z})-f(-\sqrt{z})}{f(\sqrt{z})+f(-\sqrt{z})}$$ that is, $$E(X\mid X^2)=X\,\frac{f(X)-f(-X)}{f(X)+f(-X)}$$

Comment: If $X$ is discrete, then \begin{align*} \Bbb{E}[X \mid X^2] &= \sum_{x > 0} \left( x \Bbb{P}(X = x \mid X^2 = x^2) - x \Bbb{P}(X = -x \mid X^2 = x^2) \right) \mathbf{1}_{\{X^2 = x^2\}}. \\ &= \sum_{x > 0} \Bbb{E}[X \mid X^2 = x^2] \mathbf{1}_{\{X^2 = x^2\}} \end{align*}  In other words, $X$ is averaged over each event $\{X^2 = x^2\}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Surely you realize that, as soon as $Y$ is discrete, the formula $$E(X\mid Y)=\sum_yE(X\mid Y=y)\,\mathbf 1_{Y=y}$$ is true *by definition* and vaid in full generality, hence there is nothing specific to the case $Y=X^2$ in your comment, or is there?

Comment: @Did, For me, it does tell that $\Bbb{E}[X \mid X^2]$ need not be the same as $X$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Your comment will make this clear to those who already know why, don't you think?

Comment: @Did, My intention was to demonstrate that the loss of information from $X$ to $\Bbb{E}[X \mid X^2]$ is essentially due to the averaging effect on events of the form $\{X^2 = x^2\}$, which I think is important for constructing various counter-examples. But if you think this is already hinted by others, then you are probably right.

Comment: @Did: there's nothing specific for any case. The question is about the moooost general case. The only one info I got about $X$ is that it is integrable.

Comment: @SangchulLee When looking at the $\sigma$-algebras of $X$ and $X^2$ I saw the "loss of information" too, but I didn't know how to demostrate it until you pointed out the averaging effect.

Comment: @Broken_Window I might not understand what your comment to me is about but since you felt the need to proclaim that Sangchul's comment addresses your concerns, then everything is fine, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation is fine (and [Did's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912564/is-it-true-that-exx2-x/1912576#comment3925698_1912564) deals with the case where $X$ has a pdf)), but a counterexample may be simpler.

Take $X$ to be a Rademacher random variable, i.e. uniform on $\{-1,1\}$. Then $X^2=1$ a.s., so $\mathbb{E}[X\mid X^2] = \mathbb{E}[X] = 0 \neq X$.

---

*As mentioned in a comment below, this generalizes to any symmetric (and non zero a.s.) random variable.*

Comment: Perhaps more interestingly, the counterexample stands for every (nonzero) symmetric random variable X.

Comment: @Did True -- I'll add this. Thanks!

Comment: I was getting lost trying to prove give a counterexample with negative random variables, but this one is wonderfully simpler!