# Can anyone give me an example

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Can anyone give me an example of two random variables $A$ and $B$ defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ which are not independent and for which we even though have $\mathbb{E}[A\mid B]=\mathbb{E}[A]$
 . Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to give you an outline, and leave the task of filling the details to you. The construction is inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912564/is-it-true-that-exx2-x/1912576).

Let $X$ be distributed according to your favorite non-constant non-negative distribution, say $X\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(1)$; and $Y\sim\operatorname{Rademacher}$ be a r.v. independent of $X$ ($Y$ is uniform on $\{-1,1\}$).

Then set $A\stackrel{\rm def}{=}XY$ and $B\stackrel{\rm def}{=}X$. Can you show that:

- $\mathbb{E}[A\mid B] = \mathbb{E}[A] =0$; but
- $A,B$ are *not* independent?

Comment: Interestingly, the example in the other answer is the case "X=0 or 1" of the general construction here.

Answer (score 1):

Construct $A$ and $B$ as so:

$B$ can take the values $0$ and $1$ each with probability $1/2$.

$A$ can take the values $-1$, $0$, and $1$. Conditioned on $B=1$, $A$ is either $-1$ or $1$ each with probability $1/2$. Conditioned on $B=0$, $A$ is $0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: In other words, $(A,B)$ might be uniform on $\{(-1,1),(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: @Did: Am I missing something here? Your paraphrase seems to contradict the second sentence of the answer. It appears to me that intended distribution is $\frac14,\frac12,\frac14$, not uniform.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Everything works: A conditionally on B and B both uniform (as the OP and you suggest) or (A,B) uniform (as I suggest).

Comment: @Did: Okay; I took *In other words* to mean that you were offering a simpler paraphrase of the OP’s definition rather than a simpler but different definition that would work equally well.